# Async function returning Promise even after calling Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I've been trying to create a helper function to return a document's data from the Firebase database using Nodejs:

```
module.exports = async (collectionName, documentId, res) => {
  const collection = db.doc(`/${collectionName}/${documentId}`);
  try {
    const targetedDocument = await collection.get();
    if (!targetedDocument.exists) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: true,
        message: `the document ${documentId} is not exists.`,
      });
    }
    return targetedDocument.data();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error });
  }
};
```

But when I tried to use it, it always returns back a promise:

```
const documentFinder = require('./helper-function-path');

router.post('post',(req,res)=>{
  const requiredDocument = documentFinder("post", "Izkn12IMnayzokLqe",res);
  console.log(requiredDocument); //returned a promise rather than an object document
})
```

What am I doing wrong here? Some pointer would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Async/Await can be tricky to use, please try out Promises, figure out the code flow and then replace Promise with Async/Await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async functions, by definition, always return a promise.  You can't make an asynchronous function to be synchronous simply by wrapping it.  The caller will always still have the promise to deal with.  You can deal with the returned promise in your express route by making its callback also async, and awaiting the result of the function call:

```
router.post('post', async (req,res)=>{
  const requiredDocument = await documentFinder("post", "Izkn12IMnayzokLqe",res);
  console.log(requiredDocument);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out:

```
module.exports = async (collectionName, documentId, res) => {
  const collection = db.doc(`/${collectionName}/${documentId}`);
  try {
    const targetedDocument = await collection.get();
    if (!targetedDocument.exists) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: true,
        message: `the document ${documentId} is not exists.`,
      });
    } else {
        return targetedDocument.data();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: true, message: error });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, both works, it's not returning what I wanted due to a typo or in the code :))